# Selectively disable a ligature in pdflatex + newtxtext

Tags: pdftex, typewriter, ligatures

I had a wonderfully working setup with LuaLaTeX, but my publisher demands I use PDFLaTeX and newtxtext.

This, however, replaces ">>" in monospaced text with "»" which looks very weird.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\texttt{foo<bar<bax>>}

\end{document}
```

Can I somehow selectively deactivate this ligature?

I have found a few recommended solutions:

- selnolig package
- microtype + `\DisableLigatures`

But none of them work in my setup.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

microtype works fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = T1, family = tt* }
\begin{document}

\texttt{foo<<bar<bax>>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had written `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1, family = tt* }` for some reason and that hadn't worked. This works, thank you!